# How can I stop Selenium-Webdriver from closing Firefox and throwing an error when it hits a certificate error with automation through Ruby/Rspec?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, ssl-certificate

Failure/Error: visit url
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:

I get the above error whenever visiting a URL that has an expired certificate, the Your connection is not secure page doesn't have an opportunity to load before the browser closes my test with the failure.  I've tried importing the certificate and then adding it, the latter of which fails.  I've tried creating a profile with different variations of,

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_profile do |app|  
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new  
  profile.secure_ssl = false  
  profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false  
  profile.accept_untrusted_certs = true  
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => firefox, :profile => profile)  
end
```

through about:config in Firefox I've set browser.ssl_override_behaviour from 2 to 1.  My automation navigates to other environment URLs that don't experience the certificate error and runs as it's supposed to.  I've also confirmed the URL stored in url isn't malformed.

In addition to the driver setup above, I also have

```
  require "capybara"  
  require "capybara/dsl"  
  require "capybara/rspec"  
  require "capybara-screenshot/rspec"  
  require 'selenium-webdriver'
```

in my spec_helper.rb.

Firefox 52.0.2 (32-bit)
Geckodriver 0.15.0 (32-bit)
selenium-webdriver (3.3.0)
rspec (3.5.0)
capybara (2.13.0)
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: Have you tried only using `profile.accept_untrusted_certs = true` and not using `assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false` ?

Comment: I have, it looks like what I might need is Firefox 47.0.2 and to find a legacy driver for it, unfortunately.